# How to change marker size when using Google Maps setIcon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am adding markers to a map, which are small when I originally add them. However, I then loop over them and change some of them to another marker that has the same size but a different color:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <select id="state-select" class="">
          <option value="">SELECT A STATE</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$.each(stateMarkerArr, function(index, thisStateMarker) {
    if (thisStateMarker.state == stateCode) {
        thisStateMarker.setIcon('/img/example_img.png');        
        bounds.extend(thisStateMarker.getPosition());           
    } else {
        thisStateMarker.setIcon('/img/example_img2.png');       
    }
});
```

However, the marker is being plotted as in a larger size:

[image]

How can I dynamically set the size of the marker when using the `setIcon` function, so that I can make these two markers the same size?

I was setting the original points with:

```
var icon = {
    url: '/img/example_img.png',
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28,50)
}
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: thisLocation.Store,
    state: currentState,
    icon: icon
});
```

AND then trying to set the points on the fly with:

```
$.each(stateMarkerArr, function(index, thisStateMarker) {
    if (thisStateMarker.state == stateCode) {
        var icon = {
            url: '/img/example_img.png',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28,50)
        }       
        thisStateMarker.setIcon(icon);
        bounds.extend(thisStateMarker.getPosition());           
    } else {
        var icon = {
            url: '/img/example_img2.png',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(28,50)
        }       
        thisStateMarker.setIcon(icon);              
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3tLrkwht/) both the icons are the same size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `size` or `scaledSize` properties of the `google.maps.Icon` object. See [the Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions) and [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex):

```
var icon = {url:'/img/example_img.png', size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32)};
thisStateMarker.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: This is the right code sample no-one has really bothered to add. Thank you sir!